# Updating A Content In A Div For Every Checkboxlist Datum Being Checked

Tags: php, yii

I have two divisions in my view: left and right.
The left portion displays a checkboxlist (just being rendered partially from another view and is updated through AJAX form submission). I want that for every single click for the check box, the datum being selected is automatically displayed in the right portion (and if possible, disappears again and the checkbox will be back to uncheck when I click the data in the right portion).

Need tips. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind a function to the onclick event of the checkboxes and do what you want on that function

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
  $('#right_div').append(something);
})
```

if the checkboxes appear during ajax requests you can bind the function with

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').live('click',function(){
  $('#right_div').append(something);
})
```

you can do something similar the other way, when you append the text on the right div, put something on that tag that references the checkbox, then you bind a function to the click event of that tag you just inserted